# Running roulette via JS

Tags: javascript

There is a horizontal roulette. When you open the site and start roulette, the console displays 15 times about the start of roulette from the getRandomItem() function. I put 15 objects in roulette in generateItems(), and I don't know how to run roulette 1 time, but save 15 objects in roulette. And to the object that should fall out, the Active class is added to it in the start() function

```js
const items = [
    { name: 'flami', img: '', price: 100, priceCount: 0 },
    { name: 'flami', img: '', price: 100, priceCount: 0 },
    { name: 'flami', img: '', price: 100, priceCount: 0 },
    { name: 'flami', img: '', price: 200, priceCount: 0 },
    { name: 'flami', img: '', price: 250, priceCount: 0 },
  ];
  
let balance = 2000;
let countFlip = 0;

function getRandomItem() {
    let item;

    while(!item) {
        item = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];

        if (item.price > balance * 0.20)  {
            return getRandomItem();
            } else {
            countFlip++;
            
            balance -= item.price;
            if (balance < 0) {
                console.log('Game over!');
                return;
            }
            if (countFlip % 10 === 0) {
                balance += 2000;
            }
            console.log(`You got ${item.name} for ${item.price}. Your balance is now ${balance}. ${countFlip}`);
            }
        return item;
    }
}

let isSpinning = false;

function generateItems() {
    if (isSpinning) {
        return;
    }
    isSpinning = true;

    document.querySelector('.list').innerHTML = '';
    document.querySelector('.scope').innerHTML = `<ul class="list"></ul>`;

    const list = document.querySelector('.list')
    list.innerHTML = ''

    for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        item = getRandomItem()

        const li = document.createElement('li')
        li.classList.add('list_item')
        li.innerHTML = `
            <img src ="${item.img}" alt="" />
        `
        list.append(li)
    }
}

generateItems()


function start() {
    generateItems()
    const list = document.querySelector('.list')

    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        list.style.left = '50%'
        list.style.transform = 'translate3d(-50%, 0, 0)'
    },0)

    const item = list.querySelectorAll('li')[7]

    list.addEventListener('transitionend', () =>{
        item.classList.add('active')
        isSpinning = false;
        
    })
}
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="app">
      <i class="pointer fa-solid fa-location-pin" style="font-size: 40px; color: rgb(163, 41, 41);"></i>
      <div class="scope">
        <ul class="list"></ul>
      </div>

      <button onclick="start()" class="start">Start</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your `items` array variable is undefined.